# Determining Rate of Change of an Equation

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to figure out this math problem for a while now. If anyone can help me out it would be much appreciated.

The thickness of the ice on a lake for one week is modelled by the function $T(d)= -0.1d^3+1.2d^2-4.4d+14.8$ where $T$ is the thickness in cm and $d$ is the number of days after December 31st.

a) When do you think the coolest day occured during the week? Would it be the day when the thickness of ice started to increase and thus the AROC was the greatest and positive? That's all I have been able to figure out.

b) Determine the Average rate of change on a short interval near the point you chose in a). I do know how to calculate the AROC but I don't know the point.

c) Determine the instantaneous rate of change at the point in a) I don't know how to calculate this

d) Were the answers to average and instantaneous rate of change the same? If not why? I think they would be different because the AROC is an estimate

Please help me out, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes some physical sense that the coldest day is the day the thickness is *increasing most rapidly*.

So we want to maximize the *rate of change* of thickness, that is, maximize the derivative of $T(d)$. Your answer should turn out to be $4$.

Comment: You are welcome. From your post I take it you know how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

a) The coolest day of the week would probably be the day where the function is at a global maximum.

c) Instantaneous rate of change (IROC) at a point $(a,f(a))$ is equal to $f'(a)$.

d) AROC is the average rate of change. IROC is how fast the value of the function is increasing or decreasing at a specific moment.

Comment: What do you mean by global maximum and how do you calculate it?

Comment: Find all the points on the graph where the derivative is 0 (the tangent line is horizontal), and the boundary points of the curve (d=0 and 7 in this case) Then, plug them back in to the equation and see which one is the greatest.

Comment: Actually, Andre's answer to part a) makes more sense. It would actually be when the ice thickness is increasing the most rapidly. Just apply my previous comment to $T'(d)$ instead of $T(d)$.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you, Jed!

Answer (score 0):

Some physics to get the relationship between ice sheet thickness and temperature: [ice growth](http://lakeice.squarespace.com/ice-growth/)
And allow me to use variables common to physics.

- It freezes if the temperature $T(t)$ over a certain period of time $t$, e.g. the averaged temperature over a day $T_a$, is below the melting point around $T_m = 0^\circ C = 32^\circ F$.
  Thus $T_m - T_a \ge 0$.
- The thickness of the ice sheet is $x(t)$
- The growth rate $\dot{x}$ increases with $T_m-T_a$ and is complicated, it can be approximated by $k(T_m-T_a)$, the linked article states roughly $k=1/15^\circ$ in inches per day, for certain thicknesses

a) The graph of $x$,$\dot{x}$ and $\ddot{x}$ is

[image: graph x, x dot]

The ice sheet increases in size between day 3 and 5, with the largest growth happening at day 4, as growth rate increases with higher difference to the melting point, this should be the coldest day.

b) Try 
$$
x_a = \frac{1}{2\Delta t} \int\limits_{t_0-\Delta t}^{t_0+\Delta t} \dot{x}(t) \,dt 
= \frac{1}{2\Delta t}\left( x(t_0 +\Delta t) - x(t_0-\Delta t)\right)
$$
for averaging around $t_0=4$

c) Calculate $\dot{x}(4)$

d) The instantaneous change rate $\dot{x}(t)$ corresponds to the average from b) for $\Delta t \to 0$.